# Listview lazy loading of images in imageview reuse

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view and i am lazyily loading the bitmap in the cell from the cloud.
Now the problem is, i am making a request to the service in the **getView** of the adapter, so a request is made, but when the hotel cell is being reused then there are multiple image fetch request for an imageview , so imageview image are switching between multiple images..help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `ImageView` is being recycled it now comes with a different url. You need to cancel the previous download and execute a new one. There are open sources frameworks you can Google for.

Here's one: https://github.com/mitmel/Android-Image-Cache

Even better: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared your code i am guessing you are not using holder pattern in your adapter.

The best tutorial is available by vogella.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_hoder